# How to generate two random Strings from a given LCS?

Tags: string, random, lcs

A string is given, which should be the Longest Common Subsequence(LCS) between two Strings. You have to generate two random strings(with alphabets only) having the string as their LCS ?

Please help me out to solve this by providing any reference or any idea?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  If it didn't work, why didn't it work?  What came out wrong?

Comment: OK, a hint.  If you add "B" to the end of one copy of the LCS, what should you not add to the end of the other copy?